# In Sencha 2.3.1 Checkbox value is always empty?

Tags: touch, sencha-touch-2.1

In my application i have used checkbox (right now m upgrade my sencha version 2.0 to 2.3.1) m facing problem with getting checkbox value
Here my code:

```
this.down('#rememberMeChkBoxId').getValue();
```

It return always "". In Sencha 2.0 it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You either use the form

```
this.down('.form').getValues()
```

or you need the checkbox value

```
Ext.Viewport.down('.checkboxfield').getSubmitValue()
```